# Variable not accessible outside of function Swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift, nsxmlparser

Here is the problem i am trying to parse XML in Swift everything works except for values.

```
import UIKit


class ItemParser: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate {
var parser = XMLParser()
var element:String!
var currentName:String = String()


func beginParsing()
{
    parser = XMLParser(contentsOf:(NSURL(string:"URL"))! as URL)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
{
    element = elementName
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    if element.isEqual("name") {
        currentName = string
    }
    print (currentName) -- displaying correctly
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
    if elementName.isEqual("inv") {

        print("begginging")
        print(currentName) -- displaying nothing

}
}
```

To my Understanding i have declared all variable in the correct place but the variable is not retaining outside of function. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the character value for an XML element can be huge it is possible that `foundCharacters` is called multiple times for the same element. So you have to append the characters to your class variable until `didEndElement` is being called for that element:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    if element.isEqual("name") {
        currentName += string  // append here
    }
}
```

And you have to take care on correctly resetting this variable on a new element:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
{
    element = elementName
    currentName = ""  // reset 
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
    if elementName.isEqual("inv") {

        print("begginging")
        print(currentName) // is now complete
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. The only other thing is that when i nullify it in the didStart it shows as empty but when i nullify it in the didend inside of the if statement everything works fine.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT forget XML is streaming kind of protocol - what this means is - it does not give you all the information at once, so you need to append to the info you already have. What you need to do in `foundCharacters` is:

```
currentName += string
```

and renew currentName in start/end of element parsing.

```
currentName = ""
```